# Virtualbox Android-x86 install error: cannot mount

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox, android-x86

I get "cannot mount /dev/sda1" error when I try to install android on virtual machine. I use latest version of virtual box, default options. I follow the steps in [here](http://www.androidsim.net/2011/08/how-to-37-install-android-on-virtual.html) and get stuck at 17.

Comment: Do you need an emulator for coding? Or another else?

Comment: Yes, for coding. The emulator that comes with SDK sucks and I don't have the money to buy a phone.

Comment: Oh my machine is Fedora 64bit, 2 GB RAM, Dual core. It works fine with emulator. It needs about 250MB RAM for Android 1.5 - 2.3.x, and 512MB RAM for 4.0.3. I hope it fits your machine? I think emulator is better than VirtualBox...

Comment: I have a similar issue when using VMWare
I am attempting to install nugat to a VM for emulation, and on installing and following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BckEV3FzCPo), I get stuck with [this:](https://i.imgur.com/qLeOReN.png).

Comment: Also, just noticed the date on this issue, Did the problem get solved OP?

Comment: not as far as I remember, we used real phones for testing

Comment: @4g0tt3nSou1 I added an answer, maybe it will help. I just fixed this issue but unfortunately I was not able to get Android x86 on QEMU working yet (boot stuck at the android logo screen on x86 version and reboot loop on x86_64 version).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is about VirtualBox but I got it with QEMU also so maybe the solution is the same. I was able to fix it by creating a disk with a smaller size, like 4 GB instead of 8 GB. In the documentation, they even say to use 1 GB and then mount an SD card: https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/qemu.html